# Can't Install Spin CLI (Spinnaker)

Tags: devops, spinnaker

I have Mac OS Mojave.
I am following this guide to [Install and Configure Spin CLI](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/spin/#on-macos) .

When I copy this command:

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/spinnaker-artifacts/spin/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/spinnaker-artifacts/spin/latest)/linux/amd64/spin
```

I get this error:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Details>No such object: spinnaker-artifacts/spin/latest)/darwin/amd64/spin</Details></Error>
```

Any suggestion or alternative way to install this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you change the command to use the resolved latest version? `curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/spinnaker-artifacts/spin/1.12.0/linux/amd64/spin`